# PPPOE, DHCP и динамический ip

Tags: linux, ip, tcp-ip, dhcp, pppoe

Стоял старый роутер с подключением `pppoe` и `динамическим ip`. Потребовалось в автоматическом режиме менять ip, но стоковая прошивка не поддерживала командный интерфейс (ни ssh, ни telnet). Перепрошил роутер на `openwrt` ради ssh (всё ок) и при создании подключения начались танцы. `Pppoe` подключение выкидывало ошибку и перепробовав другие протоколы, получилось подключиться по `DHCP`. Я пишу в ТП провайдеру как так, спустя 15 мин перекидывая с сотрудника на сотрудника я с горем пополам получаю ответ, что всех клиентов переводят на DHCP протокол при пересоздании подключения в автоматическом режиме и старое подключение вернуть не могут O_o.

Суть вопроса: у меня при перезагрузке роутера, ip менялся на лету (при старом подключении по `pppoe`). Сейчас при подключении по `DHCP` ip не меняется (ждал до 20 мин, отключал роутер от сети, с отключением всех интерфейсов в роутере). ТП провайдера говорит что, ip должен меняться (среднее время ожидания 10 мин при отключенном роутере), но доверия им нет (такую ахинею несли эти сотрудники ТП, что аж смешно).

`Ip` у меня `динамический` (в настройках у провайдера в ЛК), услуга статического у провайдера стоит денег.
И сейчас ip меняется только при смене `mac адреса роутера`

Ни google, ни ТП внятного ответа не дали

Я теперь не увижу динамический адрес, как это было с `PPPOE`?

p.s. Для дорогого **eri** )

```
udhcpc: started, v1.28.4
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending select for 95.79.86.227
udhcpc: lease of 95.79.86.227 obtained, lease time 1800
udhcpc: ifconfig eth1 95.79.86.227 netmask 255.255.252.0 broadcast +
udhcpc: setting default routers: 95.79.87.254
```

Comment: разные технологии подключения - разные детали реализации. ТП на то и техподдержка, что не может знать всех деталей. Допускаю, что адрес будет изменятся, но, например, раз в несколько дней (у меня так - может по несколько недель быть один и тот же, а потом раз и новый).  С другой стороны,  у Вас все же динамический адрес.

Comment: @KoVadim, но один из сотрудников сказал, что раз в 10 мин должен меняться или он просто не осведомлен и это ctrl+v ответ? Возможно у dhcp есть тонкие настройки на стороне клиента и я это не учёл?

Comment: если Ваш адрес будет меняться раз в десять минут, то ничего хорошего с этого не получится. Но на роутере всегда можно посмотреть Lease time (или как оно там будет называться) и сразу узнаете, когда он "может поменяться". А до этого ему нет смысла дергаться.

Comment: @KoVadim, сам то ip и не должен меняться, мне это надо по скрипту

Comment: тогда договаривайтесь с техподдержкой. или используйте прокси

Comment: @KoVadim, это понятно. Я вопрос задал к тому, что возможно у dhcp есть некая настройка, позволяющая запрашивать новый ip и тд и тп... И я тут с надеждой, что мне ответят)

Comment: настройка есть только она на стороне провайдера ;)... а «динамический ip» значит что он меняется когда удобно провайдеру, а не когда удобно клиенту... собственно почти наверняка сервер настроен так, что запоминает какой ip выдавался на конкретный MAC и выдаёт его же при следующем подключении... если верить ТП, то кеш сбрасывается через 10 минут при отсутствии подключения... собственно просто меняй MAC в скрипте и всё... если провайдер на такое поведение обижаться не будет, то всё должно быть нормально...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Спасибо, я уже так и думаю делать, а то что кэш сбрасывается раз в 10 мин видимо не так, потому что я ждал и по более несколько раз

Comment: ждал при отключённом соединении?(`ifdown` на интерфейсе или выдернутом кабеле)?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, роутер отключал на 15-20 мин, wan интерфейс отключал ради интереса мин на 5... С PPPOE просто перезагружая роутер получал новый ip

Comment: @Fat-Zer можно релизом освободить адрес попробовать

Comment: @Алексей кеш обычно на двое суток настраивают) отключай роутер на 2 дня, если не прокатит релиз

Comment: Вы _хотите_, чтобы он менялся? DHCP, наоборот, старается одному и тому же клиенту выдавать один и тот же адрес.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, да, я не знаю как еще яснее изложить)

Comment: @Алексей написать где-нибудь в вопросе "Хочу, чтобы роутер при каждой перезагрузке получал от провайдера другой IP-адрес", вероятно ;) Тут будет проблема с определением термина "другой" во время начальной загрузки, но хотя бы будет очевидно, чего вы хотите :)

Comment: @Алексей, а, да, уже есть (нашёл фразу "Потребовалось в автоматическом режиме менять ip..").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переподключение не поможет. Настройка сети тоже, но в openwrt маленький, но мощный дхцп клиент.

Сначала прибьем запущенный из настроек клиент, убираем старый адрес

```
killall udhcpc
ip address flush dev eth0
```

Запускаем вручную, просим адрес , например, `1.60.128.45` - если он свободен и у провайдера нет привязки - получим его, если занят, то получим старый или другой новый, не выйдет с первого раза - попробуй ещё:

```
udhcpc -i eth0 -R -r 1.60.128.45 -C
```

-R освободить адрес при выходе,

-i ван интерфейс,

-r просим этот адрес,

-C не посылаем id чтоб не получить привязку

Заранее просканируй сеть провайдера чтоб узнать свободные адреса. Если фокус не удался, то адрес привязан к порту на свиче провайдера и к договору и выйти в интернет с другим адресом не получится.

Comment: хорошая идея...

Comment: Спасибо огромное, буду пробовать

Comment: @eri, а что означает этот ответ? Фокус не удался? Обновил вопрос

Comment: это означает ты получил адрес 95.79.86.227. совпадает со старым или с запрошенным?

Comment: это старый, те который был и сейчас

Comment: кильни udhcpc, чтоб релиз ушел, пробуй ещё. Тот адрес что спросил через -r свободен?

Comment: но скорее привязка через радиус - там не  получишь новый адрес пока не закончатся адреса у провайдера.